# OptaPlanner - Global Variable is empty when calling from another rule

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm new to Drools. I have taken List of object as global variable in drl file and adding records in list in rule 1. Every time rule 1 is executed it will add the updated records in list. I want to use that list in rule 2.
But when executing rule 2 the list is getting empty.

Basically what I'm planning to achieve is as follows:

1. I will have a list of Students [PLANNING VARIABLE] (say 10)
2. I will have a list of Events (say 60) that need to be attended by the students. Each event has a venue and start and end time and are spread across throughout the day at different places.
3. I want to assign the nearest Student to the Event Venue [SOLUTION] such that the events get distributed amongst all the Students and they are assigned the event nearest to their position at that moment in time after previous event is completed.

To assign nearest Student to Event Venue, I need to maintain the Ordered List of Students based on their projected position (venue) at that time. So that the assignment rule will pickup the top most Student in the list for the Event.

Therefore the order in the list of Students will change after each assignment. I want this **changing list of Students** to be made available across the constraint rules.

my Pojo classes is:

```
public class student {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private double position;

...

//getter
//setter
}

public class Events {
    private long id;
    private String venueName;
    private double position; // venue location
    private Date startTime;
    private Date endTime;
}
```

My PLANNING ENTITY class:

```
@PlanningEntity
public class EventEntity{

private student stud;
private Events events;

    @PlanningVariable
    public student getStud() {
        return stud;
    }

//getter
//setter
}
```

My PLANNING SOLUTION class:

```
@PlanningSolution
public class EventSolution {
    private long id;
    private List<student> student;
    private List<Events> events; // venue location
...
    //getter
    //setter
}
```

Another class is:

```
public class studentRoster {

public List<student> fetchData(List<student> studList){

  List<student> studList = new ArrayList<student>();
      if(studList == null){
          //add records in studList from excel
      }else{
          // calculate the students position from event venue position and sort the list to assign nearest students 
       }

   return studList;
   }

}
```

my drl file:

```
//imports

global List<student> studentList;

rule  "rule1"
salience 6
    when
       EventEntity(events != null, $event : events)
       studList : List() from collect (EventSolution (student == null))
    then
       studentRoster sr = new studentRoster();
       studentList = sr.fetchData($event,studList); 
end

rule "rule2"
  salience 5
    when
      $stud: student() from studentList //here studentList is getting empty
    then
      System.out.println($stud);
end
```

Also tried using extend keywords but still the list getting empty

```
rule "rule2" extends "rule1"
    when
      $stud: student() from studentList
    then
      System.out.println($stud);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`global` fields are not compatible with optaplanner (with the exception of the `scoreHolder` of course), especially when later activating multithreaded solving, partitioned search, etc (because they create multiple kie sessions).

The `sr.fetchData();` code should happen before calling `solver.solve(problem)` to population the `problem`.

Btw, as you're using excell, take a look at `ConferenceSchedulingXlsxFileIO.read(File)` which returns a problem.

Comment: I think I wasnt able to communicate my query properly. I have now updated the question above. How should I be able to share that list of students across all the constraint rules?